# Making a resizable hexagon in the middle of my page for all content to feed through

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a hexagon in my page. I want virtually all content to run through the hexagon and I would like it to resize based on the browser size. Can anyone point in the right direction.

Comment: Please show the code you tried till now.

Comment: This will give you a start - http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html